# How to fix Cx_Freeze not assigning executable description

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm building my program using cx_freeze, but cx_freeze does not write the program's description specified in the setup.py file, the program is compiled fine and it does run the way it should, but the executable description is missing. How can I assign a description to my program? e.g: name = "Product Name", version = "Version number", description = "Product Description", Copyright = "Product Copyright".

When building the program I tried to run the command line with administrator permission thinking that he may not have permission to write on the file, but this method didn't work.

```py
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup
from cx_Freeze import Executable


include_files = ["database/", "images/"]
base = None

if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(name="Product Name",
      version="1.0.0",
      description="Product Description",
      options={'build_exe': {"include_files": include_files}},
      executables=[Executable("main.py",
                              base=base,
                              icon="images/product.ico")])
```

After the program is compiled the executable should present a description when the properties option is accessed.

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSa9O.png

Comment: Is it it documented anywhere that this should work in the first place?

Comment: Didn't find anything in the cx_freeze documentation, where are those values getting assigned? And how can I add that information in the executable description?